# servlet/servlet.FileDownload and Zoom with iOS Salesforce1?

Tags: salesforce1-app, ios

I'm just prototyping at the moment and I've created a link on an Apex page that when clicked will get documents on-premise via Azure Service Bus Relay.  The contents are then return as base64 and an attachment is created.  This all works.

The attachment is then downloaded to the user using /servlet/servlet.FileDownload which seems to work fine in a standard browser (including the ability to Zoom) but on Salesforce1 on iOS (I've not tried it on Android) it downloads OK but you can't zoom using pinch gestures.  Also, it would be good to get an idea of the download progress but that doesn't seem to work 'out of the box' either.  At the moment, using Salesforce1, you click on the link and the file downloads but the user doesn't get any feedback until the document has been fully downloaded and displayed to the user.

I'm a noob with Salesforce so if anyone has any ideas it will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Steve

**Update 8th Feb**

It looks like Salesforce1 is based on PhoneGap/Cordova which uses the iOS UIWebView 'under the covers' but for some unknown reason when a webview is embedded as a Salesforce1 page you don't seem to get zoom or the ability to view as landscape.

As a test I created a Custom Link on a Salesforce layout to open a PDF file and that opens up the PDF in a new window (which is not a child of the Salesforce1 and it also includes a Close button) interestingly zoom and rotation then work when viewing PDFs.

I've tried a number of things to replicate this from an Apex page, even trying to replicate the layout's Html & Js but sadly Salesforce1 still doesn't want to play ball.

I've also tried to replicate the opening to a new window via

```
javascript:window.open
```

but that also doesn't seem to work on Salesforce1 (just opens the view in a child window within Salesforce1).

On a positive note it looks like Salesforce1 will be using iOS WKWebView with Spring '17 so that should, I hope, come out in the next week or two.  Hopefully that will fix my zoom issue 'as is'.

**New and Improved Web View Available in Salesforce1 for iOS version 12.0**
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=New-and-Improved-Web-View-Available-in-Salesforce1-for-iOS-version-12-0&language=en_US&type=1

Comment: You need to make your apex page compatible with Salesforce1, Please avoid using VF tages as many of them are not supported in Salesfroce1, that's an official statement, [See this page](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce1.meta/salesforce1/vf_dev_best_practices_approaches_mixed.htm)
Use HTML tags or you can also use any Mobile enabled UI framework like Bootstrap. To detect the zoom by fingers, you can enable you Apex page with some custom framework like [Hammer.js](http://hammerjs.github.io/)

Comment: Thanks for this, the page 'simply' returns a PDF document so I think I'm going to wait now to see how Sf1 works with WKWebView, which I have a feeling will fix my problem albeit the users will have to all be on iOS 10.